# Debian package available for ia64 but not for x86_64?

Tags: debian, compiling, 64bit, x86, cpu-architecture

I want to download `aptitude` to build it from source on my 64bit machine.
It is a Thinkpad with a normal x86_64 CPU, nothing special.

The [download page](http://packages.debian.org/unstable/admin/aptitude) only has:

- alpha
- amd64
- armel
- armhf
- hppa
- hurd-i386
- i386
- ia64
- kfreebsd-amd64
- kfreebsd-i386
- m68k
- mips
- mipsel
- powerpc
- powerpcspe
- ppc64
- s390
- s390x
- sh4
- sparc
- sparc64
- x32

I find it hard to believe x86_64 is not available.
Am I missing something?

Note: I believe ia64 is for Itanium, so not for me.

Comment: [Because Debian had an amd64 port before Intel sold amd64 processors.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53415/why-are-64-bit-distros-often-called-amd64)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is called "amd64".
"ia64" it's Itanium, "i386" is 32bit Intel 386.
The 64bit architecture was originally developed by AMD, and then adopted by Intel.