# Does Linux on Ryzen 7 (4700U) use the same software (e.g. kernel, drivers, & packages) as for intel CPUs (Core i5, i7, etc)?

Tags: linux, amd

I hope to install GNU/Linux Mint or possibly Debian on a Ryzen 7 laptop (as a dual boot).  (Specifically, on a new HP x360.)

**Will I be using the same binaries (installers, downloads and packages) as if the laptop was running Intel's Core i5 or i7?**

I understand that there are some things that possibly don't work perfectly, but I'm not asking about that here.  I just want to know if I'll have to look for software specifically compiled for Ryzen or not.

Comment: @muru, Why did you remove the 'ryzen' tag?  Because AMD makes a number of CPUs, like Athlon for example that is quite different from Ryzen, and I wasn't asking about AMD processors in general.  I asked this question because I had already spent several hours searching for an answer to this question.  .. surprised that someone hadn't asked it before.

Comment: Also it would be nice if whoever marked this down, would explain why they did that in a comment here.  .. Especially when there have already been 4 people who upvoted the answer.  (BTW, this isn't even my machine, thought I would like it if it was, it's a friends.)

Comment: Why do you need the Ryzen tag when it is an AMD CPU, and this is a question about Linux? First use the tags that are already applicable to the question.

Comment: As to being Ryzen-specific, Ryzen isn't using some groundbreaking new architecture. It's still amd64 just like Athlon. There's nothing to be surprised about - if you'd known about amd64, you'd have found questions like https://askubuntu.com/q/54296/158442 or its several duplicates or https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/53415/70524 and so on. Nothing special about Ryzen to merit a tag.

Comment: @muru and then amd is just a sucky intel second-sourcer, how did they deserve their own [tag:amd] tag on stackexchange? exterminate it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The installer is the same, and nearly all the packages are the same. In Debian terms, PCs based on Core i5/i7/... and Ryzen CPUs share the same architecture, `amd64`.

The only difference is in the microcode update packages: on Intel CPUs, you need [`intel-microcode`](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/intel-microcode), for AMD CPUs, you need [`amd64-microcode`](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/amd64-microcode).

Comment: From a comparison of instructions between Ryzen and AMD's FX line (i.e. the predecessor to Ryzen) I can see via https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ryzen, that there are a number of new instructions for Ryzen.  Does Linux take advantage of these, and if so how?  I would think that libraries would need to be compiled differently.  For example the BMI2 and SHA instruction groups were added, and FMA4 group was removed.  (It's been a long time since I've coded in assembly, and I admit that I haven't kept up with the subtle changes to the 86 line along the way over the years as it has evolved.)

Comment: The kernel uses some of these on CPUs which support them; see for example [the optimised SHA-256 implementation](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/x86/crypto/sha256_ni_asm.S). It checks for the availability of these instructions at run-time. Some libraries use this approach too. More general support requires rebuilding with model-specific compiler settings.

Comment: Thanks very much!