# dpkg-deb treats my architecture as amd64 instead of x86-64

Tags: dpkg, x86, amd, architecture

I just created a simple `.deb` package (using [this tutorial](https://www.internalpointers.com/post/build-binary-deb-package-practical-guide)). This is my control file:

```
Package: bla
Version: 1.0
Architecture: x86_64
Maintainer: bla
Description: bla
```

The `Architecture` I got from `uname -m`: `x86_64`, however, `dpkg-deb` broke due to `_` being an invalid char, so I changed to `-` which worked but broke on the installation phase:

```
dpkg: error processing archive bla_x86_64.deb (--install):
 package architecture (x86-64) does not match system (amd64)
```

So I turned to use `amd64` as my architecture, and voila!

Now I just don't understand this mismatch in architectures between `uname -m` and `dpkg`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For historical reasons, [the 64-bit x86 architecture in Debian is `amd64`](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/). The kernel identifies itself as `x86-64` but Debian packages specify `amd64`.

Other architectures have different names depending on context too, *e.g.* `arm64` instead of `aarch64`. [The architecture specifics memo on the Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/ArchitectureSpecificsMemo) gives all the details.

See also [Why are 64-bit distros often called 'amd64'?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/53415/86440)

Comment: Does this phenomena happen in other architectures as well?

Comment: Yes, Debian has specific names for each architecture, and they might not match what one might expect, or the kernel’s name for the arch, or the evolution of the architecture (*e.g.* `i386` which is really `i686` now).